# Is this mold? Picture taken after treating with bleach

Tags: insulation

[image: attic roof 2 yrs ago it was in pristine condition prior to reno.] Shake and rake insulation is on the ceiling with no vapor barrier beneath it..  bats of R 19  with paper vapor barrier are inner walls. There was no air sealing done at all. I'm afraid to reuse the insulation even though I have not seen any mold in/on it. Please advise on the mold removal process. I read lemon and salt mixture will kill what bleach didn't. Is this a wives tale? If I starve the mold spores of its moist environment, will this ensure no regrowth? I live in zone 6 and am having proper ventilation installed. I have a roof ridge, but need vents under the gable.

Comment: It looks like mold.  Bleach should kill it, but you need an adequate concentration, and you need to saturate the surface and keep it moist with bleach for 5 - 10 minutes (respray as it soaks in and dries).  A bigger concern is why it's there.

Comment: thx. I'm using full strength bleach applied with a super soaker. Yes, a toy. It shoots far, and I can get the heck out of there. It is there because my builder did not air seal attic floor. I'm in the process now.I plan to place moisture barrier, and have soffets installed as insurance

Comment: it can be caused by a lot of things; bathroom vent mishaps, condensation of warm moist air on a cold (under-insulated) roof, improper sealing, improper venting, etc.