# Is this mold? Is it dangerous mold?

Tags: roof, mold, water-damage

My elderly parents live in a condo.

They saw a leak in the attic crawl space a few weeks ago.  I went to take a look myself.

Referencing these posts, it sure seems like mold to my untrained eye.

`https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126501/is-this-mold-picture-taken-after-treating-with-bleach
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/127678/is-this-mold-mildew-or-just-dirt`

The +FRONT+ roof slope crawl space looks like this:
[image: front attic slope underside]

The +REAR+ roof slope crawl space looks much cleaner than the front:
[image]

Questions:

Is the first photo mold?
Is it dangerous mold?
Is it dangerous down to the lower living levels?

Aren't home owners associations generally responsible for things like roof leaking?

Looks like a total roof rebuild to me, but this is my amateur opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first photo could well be mold. Testing will confirm/deny. As to danger, the answer is, 'probably, yes, it presents a hazard to occupants'. There are lots of variables to consider, though.

It is very common for HOAs to be responsible for roofing, but you need to contact theirs to see. A paper trail is very important in matters like this.

A mold remediation specialist can weigh in on the rebuild versus rehabilitate question, but my instinct says that you'd want to strip off and replace the affected sheathing.